# Reponse is NULL from HttpPost with PHP Android

Tags: android

those json content are use to pass `sync.php`

```
{"details":[
{"Ticket_Date":"2014-02-11 13:09:10","Ticket_No":1,"Amount":1.2,"In_Out":"OUT","Vehicle_ID":1,"From_LocationID":1,"PriceType_ID":0,"Trip_ID":"876eb7c87d6ef156-207949831985","To_LocationID":3,"Inspector_Print ":1,"Driver_ID":1},
{"Ticket_Date":"2014-02-11 13:31:49","Ticket_No":2,"Amount":2,"In_Out":"OUT","Vehicle_ID":1,"From_LocationID":2,"PriceType_ID":0,"Trip_ID":"876eb7c87d6ef156-294637601577","To_LocationID":9,"Inspector_Print ":1,"Driver_ID":1}
]}
```

this is my Android JAVA coding

```
 public void sendJson(final JSONObject json) {
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
                HttpResponse response;

                try {
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("localhost/BusTicket/sync/sync.php");
                 // Prepare JSON to send by setting the entity
                    httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8"));

                    // Set up the header types needed to properly transfer JSON
                    httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "application/json");
                    httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US");
                    response = client.execute(httpPost);

                    /*Checking response */
                    if(response!=null){ //RESPONSE IS NULL !!!!
                        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
                        Log.d(null,"Sync Reponse= "+ in.toString()); 
                    }

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Looper.loop(); //Loop in the message queue
            }
        };
    }
```

and this is my sync.php code

```
<?php
echo 'true'
?>
```

response is null, WHY? what is the problem in my JAVA?

or have any solution to post json to php page?

Comment: is your request POST? or PUT?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour this is my full code, i have updated, i think is by default request is POST, i didn't mention which request i m using

Comment: Then shouldn't you get POST request in php with $_POST ?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour $_POST['json'] in PHP script ?

Comment: Please first get a dump from $_POST. `var_dump($_POST)` . Then check whether you can see your data or not?

Comment: @AliMasudianPour `InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();` still display nothing

Comment: @AliMasudianPour `<?php
echo var_dump($_POST); ?>` display nothing too

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47990/discussion-between-ali-masudianpour-and-chin-ye)